# Control JQuery Multi-Step Form By Browser Back Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how did they control the multi-step form using browser back button, Veterans United and Canada Drives does it. I have a multi-step form controled by Jquery what I need to do is to copy their style that instead of changing the page when you click the browser back button it will just go to previous step.

Thanks

https://www.veteransunited.com/

https://www.canadadrives.ca/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like they're using [history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

Pushstate when user clicks on the continue button.
`history.pushState(obj, "title", "#")`

And listening for popstate event which is fired when user clicks browser back button.

Comment: Thanks @yezzz, I will try that. It is very user friendly specially if you have a JQUERY multi-step form, some user click the browser back button to edit the previous entry rather than clicking your script back button, some of them use browser back button rather than clicking the html back button. and if they do that instead of navigating to previous fields it will redirect to previous page and the result instead of getting a new lead user will just close the page because they don't want to fill up the form again back to start :)

Comment: Yeah, shouldn't be that hard to tie together popstate and going back in the form. When user clicks back on the form you can use history.back() to keep things in sync.